# Get filename with subfolder jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an input form and i am getting filename in this way:

```
$(document).on('change', '.inputfile', function() {
            var name = ($(this).val().split('\\').pop());   
}
```

This gives me only the name with extension (i.e. example.csv). I would like to have the full filename if file selected is in a subfolder, like test/example.csv.
How can i have this using jquery/javascript?

Comment: Can you show example of full file address?

Comment: I don't need the full path. Only the subdirectories from root. @Mohammad

Comment: I mean file address is like `c:\\folder\\file.ex` or `domain/page/file.ex`?

Comment: Address like domain/page/file.ex. Is it possible? @Mohammad

Comment: If type of input is `file` and you want to get address of selected file, no, you can't.